# JQuery ajax executing multiple times on switch toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a table list of all the outlets, I have a materialize CSS button to activate or deactivate the outlet,

```
@foreach($outlets as $outlet)
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="switch m-b-md" data-id="{{$outlet->id}}">
            <label>
                @if($outlet->status == 'active')
                    <input id="agent-status" type="checkbox" checked="">
                @else
                    <input id="agent-status" type="checkbox">
                @endif
                <span class="lever"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

the issue is when I click on `.switch` ajax is executing multiple times, if I keep toggling the switch it is executing more than 5 to 10 times

```
$(document).on("click", ".switch", function() {

    var outlet_id = $(this).data('id');

    $(".switch").find("input[type=checkbox]").on("change",function() {

        var status = $(this).prop('checked');

        if(status == true) {
            status = "active";
        } else {
            status = "inactive";
        }

        $.ajax ({
            url: '/manager/outlets/'+outlet_id+'/status',
            type: 'POST',              
            data: {"id": outlet_id, "status": status, "_token": '{{ csrf_token() }}'},
            success: function(data)
            {   
                if(data.status==true) {
                    swal("Updated", "Status updated successfully", "success");
                } else if(data.status==false) {
                    swal("Failed", "Fail to update status try again", "error");
                }
            },
            error: function(error)
            {
                swal("Failed", "Fail to update status try again", "error");
            }
        });

    });

});
```

thank you

Comment: From your code: each time user clicks on `.switch` your code adds NEW `change` event listener, so if user clicks on `.switch`  twice, you'll have two equal event listeners in memory and each next click will add new and new listeners

Comment: @MysterX thanks for your response, could you please tell me how to handle this

Comment: Added as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need just separate your event listeners and use `outlet_id` as closure to have access to it from both listeners. See below:

```
    var outlet_id;

    $(document).on("click", ".switch", function() {

        outlet_id = $(this).data('id');

    });

    $(".switch").find("input[type=checkbox]").on("change",function() {

        var status = $(this).prop('checked');

        if(status == true) {
            status = "active";
        } else {
            status = "inactive";
        }

        $.ajax ({
            url: '/manager/outlets/'+outlet_id+'/status',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {"id": outlet_id, "status": status, "_token": '{{ csrf_token() }}'},
            success: function(data)
            {
                if(data.status==true) {
                    swal("Updated", "Status updated successfully", "success");
                } else if(data.status==false) {
                    swal("Failed", "Fail to update status try again", "error");
                }
            },
            error: function(error)
            {
                swal("Failed", "Fail to update status try again", "error");
            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop creates multiple div with the same class `switch`, when you click on the class, all div with `switch` class calls for `ajax` post. therefore, please `id` for each of your div in your loop.

```
<div class="switch m-b-md" id="div_{{$outlet->id}}" onclick="callAjax('div_{{$outlet->id}}')">
```

Your `ajax`:

```
function callAjax(divid){

   //do your ajax call here.....

}
```

Answer (score 1):

it is happening because each time a switch is clicked, a listener is added, you shouldn't have this nested listeners,

what i would do is add delegate function for checkbox change on all input type checkbox, i would give these inputs a class to simplify my selection

```
$(".switch").on('change','.CheckBoxClass', function(){
var theid = $(this).parent('.switch').data('id');
var status = $(this).prop('checked');
//add the rest of your code
});
```